# Top reasons for temp tablespace to go offline

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-11g, rdbms, oracle-19c

It was marked offline and it is fixed already.
We want to know the list of causes that marks the temp tablespace offline.

Comment: The top 1 reason is someone runs `ALTER TABLESPACE`.

Comment: There is no reason that it would *automatically* go offline while the database is running.

Comment: All right. The only reason is ALTER TABLESPACE